# Make a .sh file reading from a xml file

Tags: xml, bash, awk, cygwin, gawk

I have one file channels.xml with one structure like this, is long 4000 lines

```
<!--begin_channel-->
Rai 1.png
<!--end_channel-->
Rai 1 +2HD.png
Rai 1 +1HD.png
<!--begin_channel-->
Rai 2.png
<!--end_channel-->
Rai 2 +2HD.png
Rai 2 +1HD.png
.
.
```

I need make one file channels.sh like this:

```
cp /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/Rai_1.png /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/Rai_1_+2HD.png
cp /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/Rai_1.png /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/Rai_1_+1HD.png
cp /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/Rai_2.png /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/Rai_2_+2HD.png
cp /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/Rai_2.png /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/Rai_2_+1HD.png
```

I need do it with cygwin, I have one script can do it under ubuntu, but with cygwin is not working. This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#colori
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
NC='\033[0m'

if [ $# -ne 4 ]
then
    echo -e "${RED}ERRORE${NC}, inserire $0 filein fileout pathlogo_from pathlogo_to"
    echo -e "${RED}Ricorda${NC} le enstensioni!"
    exit 0
fi

if [ -f $2 ]
then
    echo -n -e "File $2 esistente, vuoi ${RED}sovrascrivere${NC}?(Y/n) "
    read scelta
    if [ $scelta != 'Y' ]
    then
        exit 0
    else
        rm $2
    fi
fi
awk '/\<!--begin_channel--\>/{flag=1; next} /\<!--end_channel--\>/{flag=0} flag' $1 > temp

while read line 
do
    awk "/$line/,/<!--begin_channel-->/ " $1 | grep -v "$line" | grep -v "^<" > tmp
        for channel in `cat tmp`
        do
            channel=`echo $channel | tr ")" "_" | tr "(" "_" | tr ":" "_"`
            echo  "cp $3/$line $4/$channel"
        done

done <temp >> $2
rm temp
rm tmp
echo -e "${GREEN}File $2 creato correttamente${NC}"
```

I think the error is about this line

```
awk "/$line/,/<!--begin_channel-->/ " $1 | grep -v "$line" | grep -v "^<" > tmp
```

To run it I use the command

```
{ bash }  »./script.sh channels.xml channels.sh /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/ /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/
```

Can someone help me to fix it or write one new?

Comment: Please explain what, "but with cygwin is not working", means? Are there error messages?  My first thought would be that you are using the wrong tool as you should be using something that can read xml files, like xmllint

Comment: The script look like run, but at the end I recive one error like " I can't delete tmp file not found " and I can find the file channels.sh but is empty. Look like cygwin don't like the second command awk. The script run with gawk under ubuntu and I don't know the version is installed in cygwin. Maybe is only a small error about the construction of the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tapiocapioca: Try: You could take output into a file or script as per your requirement and let us know then.

```
awk -vlines=$(cat Input_file | wc -l) -vsource="/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/" -vtarget="/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/" '/<!--end_channel/{getline;while($0 !~ /<!--begin_channel/){print "cp " source SOURCE OFS target $0;if(NR==lines){exit};getline}} /<!--begin_channel/{getline;SOURCE=$0;next}'  Input_file
```

NON-one liner form of solution as follows too:

```
awk -vlines=$(cat Input_file | wc -l) -vsource="/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/" -vtarget="/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/" '
        /<!--end_channel/{
                                getline;
                                while($0 !~ /<!--begin_channel/){
                                                                                print "cp " source SOURCE OFS target $0;
                                                                                if(NR==lines){
                                                                                                exit
                                                                                             };
                                                                                getline
                                                                             }
                         }
       /<!--begin_channel/{
                                getline;
                                SOURCE=$0;
                                next
                          }
                                                                                                                                                                  '   Input_file
```

Comment: I recive the error "cat: file333: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Tapiocapioca: I apologies this was very initial answer where my Input_file was file333, I had changed them to Input_file now. Try with your actual Input_file name in both the places of code and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: Is perfect! Really thank you about your help, if you will be in Indonesia one day you have one beer paid ;)
Ps. If I want also replace | with one space can I do it with your command?

Comment: Cool(thanks for offer), happy to help, You could mark it as correct answer(for other people's help in future) and could provide a up vote candy if you like :)

Comment: Ps. If I want also replace | with one space can I do it with your command?
I am checking to select this answer to be correct, I never did it...

Comment: Make answer correct is a TICK option and upvote is to give a up voting for a good answer(you will come to know when you start using stack overflow site more :) ). Is your new requirement is different or in the same one? It is not clear. If this is a new requirement I would suggest to open a new thread(make sure similar questions are not asked in here), if it is new then make a new post, in case of any editing in above requirement itself, please post it more clearly, thank you.

Comment: I think I choose the correct flag to mark the correct answer, is the green one right? I hope yes :)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I am not a fan of brute force, here are some options:

```
awk -vsource="/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/"
    -vtarget="/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ServerCare/data/picons/duplicati/"
    '/begin_channel/{getline src;gsub(/ /,"_",src)}
     /end_channel/{for(i=1;i<3;i++){
       getline dest;gsub(/ /,"_",dest);
       print "cp",source src,target dest}}' xml_file
```

Now the nice thing about the above is, once you are happy that the output is correct, you can simply place a pipe (|) between the print and "cp" and it will deliver the output to the shell and make the copies happen or if you really need to make an intermediate script for some reason, leave the pipe out and simply redirect the awk into channels.sh

Here's a bash alternative too:

```
xml="$1"
script="$2"
src_path="$3"     
dest_path="${src_path}duplicati/"     

get_src=0     
get_dest=0     

while read -r line     
do     
  if [[ "$line" =~ begin_channel ]]     
  then     
    get_src=1     
    get_dest=0     
  elif [[ "$line" =~ end_channel ]]     
  then     
    get_dest=1     
    get_src=0     
  else     
    (( get_src == 1 )) && src="${src_path}${line// /_}"     

    if (( get_dest == 1 ))     
    then     
      dest="${dest_path}${line// /_}"     
      echo "cp $src $dest"     
    fi     
  fi     
done<"$xml">"$script"
```